# How to Show Categories and multilevel Subcategories in Codeigniter Dropdown list

Tags: codeigniter

Hello Friends i am New in Codeigniter i have no Experience in any project i am making Shopping Website for Learning Purpose only not Real Project.When Creating Admin Panel I am Able to Fetch Categories and Subcategories tree using Loop but how to get these categories in Dropdown Menu in Tree format.

```
Like this-
Electronics
    ->Phones
        ->Tablets
        ->Mobiles
    ->Computer
        ->Laptops
        ->Desktops
Furniture
    ->Tables
        ->Plastic Table
        ->Wooden Table
```

My Model is :-

```
function getcategories($parent_id = 0) {
                $categories = array();
                $this->db->where('parentid',$parent_id);
                $query = $this->db->get('categories');
                $result = $query->result_array();
                    foreach ($result as $mainCategory) {
                    $category                           = array();
                    $category['id']                     = $mainCategory['id'];
                    $category['categoryname']           = $mainCategory['categoryname'];
                    $category['parentid']               = $mainCategory['parentid'];
                    $category['sub_categories']         = $this->getcategories($category['id']);
                    $categories[$mainCategory['id']]    = $category;
                    }
                    return $categories;

        }
```

My Categories array is Look like this:-

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [categoryname] => Electronics
                    [parentid] => 0
                    [sub_categories] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [categoryname] => Smartphones
                                    [parentid] => 1
                                    [sub_categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4
                                                    [categoryname] => Sony
                                                    [parentid] => 2
                                                    [sub_categories] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [categoryname] => Televisions
                                    [parentid] => 1
                                    [sub_categories] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

my database table look like this:-
[it is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx1gj.png)

Comment: First of all why you want to display all the hierarchical data in select dropdown as it is not good practice to do so. Dropdown is for listing items.

Comment: i want to display for when creating products there should be select Categories and i think this is essential.And if you are think this is not good practice then when i create products how can i define products under categories.

Comment: when i create a products like iphone 7 then i will give it under category Electronics->smartphones

Comment: so plz help me and if you suggest any other solution then i can also apply that.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Mac-Like-Hierarchical-Data-Displaying-Plugin-For-jQuery-hColumns.html

Comment: Multi level category multiselect CodeIgniter
https://github.com/hamedhossani/Multi_level_category_multiselect_CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
   function getcategories($parent_id = 0) {
            $categories = array();
            $category   = array(); 
            $subcategories = array();
            $q = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $parent_id));  
            $results = $q->result(); 
            foreach ($results as $mainCat) { 
                $q2 = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $mainCat->id));
                $results2 = $q2->result(); 
                foreach ($results2 as $key => $subCat) {
                    $subcategory['id']          = $subCat->id;
                    $subcategory['name']        = $subCat->name;
                    $subcategory['parentid']    = $subCat->parent_id;
                    $subcategories[$subCat->id] = $subcategory;
                }                         
                $category['id']           = $mainCat->id;
                $category['name']         = $mainCat->name;
                $category['parentid']     = $mainCat->parent_id; 
                $category['subcat']       = $subcategories;
                $categories[$mainCat->id] = $category;
                $subcategories='';                  

            } 
            return $categories;
        }
```